# Could not find goal in custom maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to develop a custom Maven plugin, i am following the tutorial from the official maven documentation as described here:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

However, when i try to use my plugin from a different project i get the following:

```
Could not find goal 'generateProtoClasses' in plugin com.myComapny.maven.plugin:myCompany-protobuf-plugin:1.0 among available goals -> [Help 1]
```

This is my MOJO:

```
@Mojo(name = "generateProtoClasses", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_RESOURCES)
public class CompileProtoClasses extends AbstractMojo {


    @Parameter(defaultValue = "mokmok")
    private String inputPath;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        getLog().info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        getLog().info(inputPath);
    }

}
```

This is the snippet on the pom.xml file of the project using the plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.myCompany.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>legolas-protobuf-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <inputPath>yoyo</inputPath>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generateProtoClasses</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Pom of the plugin project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myCompany.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>myCompany-protobuf-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>protobuf-plugin Maven Plugin</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- dependencies to annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <!-- annotations are not needed for plugin execution so you can remove 
                this dependency for execution with using provided scope -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- generated help mojo has a dependency to plexus-utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using the maven-plugin-annotations ? Can you show the pom of the plugin?

Comment: added pom of the plugin

Comment: Change the name of your class into **WhatEverMojo** and retest. Check if it could be a problem having mixed case as you have in you class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it work if you use the old-style xdoclet annotations?

```java
/**
 * @goal generateProtoClasses
 * @phase generate-resources
 */
public class CompileProtoClasses extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * @parameter default-value="mokmok"
     */
    private String inputPath;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        getLog().info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        getLog().info(inputPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Likewise, I was stuck with Maven 3.0.5 and couldn't easily change this across our environments, and removing the @Mojo annotation and replacing it with the xdoclet style annotations worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

add the following to your build->maven-plugin-plugin

```
<execution>
  <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>descriptor</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: I think that this is the right question. When using annotations to define your mojo (not doclets), you need this execution to enable mojo recognition when using the mojo.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error with maven 3.0.5 (Netbeans Build-In)
Get the latest maven version and build the maven-plugin again.